# Website not loading on LAMP but test page displays

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, lamp

I have set up my LAMP server on Ubuntu 14.04. I have created a virtual machine to host a website. The directory structure is:

```
var/www/DS/public_html
```

I have set up my configuration files so that the server responds to the url:

```
http://ds.local
```

I have created test pages inside public_html called index.html and index.php. I have modified the configurations so that index.php is the default page that gets served. In the test page named index.php, the only line of code is:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

when I go to http://ds.local frrom my browser, the page gets served up and I can see all my php configurations. So. everything good till now.

I have a website which I had developed on WAMP. Now, when I try transferring the files of this website into public_html and try reloading the browser, nothing happens. I have looked at the developer tools window, and I am certain that no page loads.

I have ensured that I have copied all the files and folders making up the website, including all the folders containing js and css. I have also ensured that there exists a file called index.php

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a website which I had developed on WAMP

Are you sure that all files are referenced by correct case?
Windows file systems are by default case-insensitive.

http://localhost/DS and http://localhost/ds

are same on windows but not on linux/unix.

Comment: My folder is in caps; i.e. DS, but I configured apache to respond to http://ds.local